# Unable to insert an Object into Database in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I'm a `laravel` beginner, didn't found a solution for my problem.

I created a form to enter the urlname into `database` - which works fine.
But for the `pagespeed` variable I always get this error:

This is part of my Controller:

```
//Create URL
$url = new URL;
$url->urlname= $request->input('urlname');
$url->pagespeed= $pspeed;

//Save url
$url->save();

//Return redirect
return redirect('/');
```

I put this in my migration:

```
public function up()
{

}
```

Maybe someone can help me with this.

Comment: Can you show your model URL ? do you set up the $fillable attribute ?
Also, the error suggest $pspeed is an object, you can push an object to as string field. Try to var_dump it to see what you can use or json_encode() it (or serialize() ) to make it a string. 
If you do that, change the type to text() in the migration as string is a varchar with max 255 char.

Comment: Store this `$pspeed->getResults('https://www.example.com');` to any variable and then `print_r()` and `echo` that variable and check what you getting exactly an array or a json string,
after that do further.

Answer (score 0):

You need to save `getResults()` function result rather than whole object, try this way:

```
public function create(Request $request) {
    $pspeed = new \PageSpeed\Insights\Service();
    $pspeedResult = $pspeed->getResults('https://www.example.com');

    //Create URL
    $url = new URL;
    $url->urlname = $request->input('urlname');
    $url->pagespeed = json_encode($pspeedResult);

    //Save url
    $url->save();

    //Return redirect
    return redirect('/');
}
```

When fetching data back from the database, remember about decoding data from json to array `$data = json_decode($url->pagespeed, true);`

You can also use [mutators](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-mutators#array-and-json-casting) instead manual decoding/encoding your arrays.

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class URL extends Model
{
    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'pagespeed' => 'array',
    ];
}
```

Comment: Now i'm getting this:  SQLSTATE[22001]: String data, right truncated: 1406 Data too long for column 'pagespeed' at row 1

Is it possible to only store the Speed Score in the pagespeed column?

Error Message says that this will be inserted into the row:
{"kind":"pagespeedonline#result","id":"https:\/\/www.example.com\/","responseCode":200,"title":"Example Domain","ruleGroups":{"SPEED":{"score":100}},"pageStats":{"numberResources":1,"numberHosts":1, etc.

Comment: you need to update your database schema, `$table->string('pagespeed');` string has too small capacity, use `text()` instead

Answer (score 0):

```
// You are making a new PageSpeed object
$pspeed = new \PageSpeed\Insights\Service();

// Next you are getting the results for an url.
// You are not assigning the results to any variable
$pspeed->getResults('https://www.example.com');

...

// Now you are trying to fill the $url->pagespeed with 
// the PageSpeed object instead of the results.
// This cause the error.
$url->pagespeed= $pspeed;
```

Solution could be:

```
$pspeed = new \PageSpeed\Insights\Service();

// Assigning it to a variable:
$results = $pspeed->getResults('https://www.example.com');

...

// Storing the results, instead of the PageSpeed object
$url->pagespeed= $results;
```

Attention that getResults(...) returns an array.

Comment: thx! changed the column type to text() ... I'm getting a lot of data in the column now. Is it possible to filter only for the 'score' ? 

got this in the column now: '{"kind":"pagespeedonline#result","id":"https:\/\/www.example.com\/","responseCode":200,"title":"Example Domain","ruleGroups":{"SPEED":{"score":100}},"pageStats":{"numberResources":1,"numberHosts":1,"totalRequestBytes":"37"' etc.

Comment: Try to save only score then `$url->pagespeed = $pspeedResult['score']` or `$url->pagespeed = Arr::get($pspeedResult, 'score')`

Comment: @veNuker thx for your help, but i'll get: Undefined index: score when using 
`$url->pagespeed = $pspeedResult['score']` and `$url->pagespeed = Arr::get($pspeedResult, 'score')` gives me: Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Arr' not found

Comment: `$pspeedResult['ruleGroups']['SPEED']['score']` for future reference you can use `dd($pspeedResult)` to check where exactly in the array score value is. As a side note, "Arr class not found", you need to import this class first, similar as you import your URL class.

Answer (score 0):

You need to encode your object first in json so that you can store it in string type column.

So

```
$pspeed->getResults('https://www.example.com');
$url->pagespeed= $pspeed;
```

Needs to be changed into

```
$results = $pspeed->getResults('https://www.example.com');
$url->pagespeed= json_encode($results );
```